# shall I write different function to validate different form in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I have maintained an array with following strings class I-V,colleglevel,engineering based on the tutor selection I want to show the form.For understanding I show the form with tutor selection with class I-V.Assume I am tutor. I selected select class I_V ,collegelevel,engineering based on this I have showed three form for them. Now I want to validate the form. shall I need to write different function for this or one function with any argument passing type.because you can see after the form I have maintained only one submit with tell about yourself field.see this tell about yourself field is common for all the form. where to write the validation for tutor based selection.

if tutor selected classI-V I need to validate only class I-V ,if tutor selected classI_V and collegelevel I need to validate both For this shall I need to wirte different validation.or using using one validation we can control all validation code.

```
 <form name="f1" action="" method="post">     
        if (isset($_POST['tutorsubject']))
                {
                    $product = $_POST['segment'];
                    $_SESSION["segment"] = $product;
                  //  print_r($product);
            $people = array("Class I-V Tuition", "Class VI-VIII Tuition", "Class IX-X Tuition", "Class XI-XII Tuition","College Level","Engineering Subjects","Technology");for($i=0; $i<count($product); $i++){
                if (in_array($product[$i], $people)) {
                    if($product[$i]=="Class I-V Tuition"){

                        ?>
                                    <tr>
                                    <Td></Td>
                                    <td><p style="color:#06F;"><?php echo $product[$i];?></p></td>
                                    </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><p style="color:#999; font-size:14px; text-align:right;">Please select your Board :</p></td>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="cbse">CBSE
            <input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="cse/Ise">ICSE/ISE
            <input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="State">State
            <input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="International">International
            </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
if($product[$i]=="college level")
{
college level form here///
}
        }
        }
    Tell about yourself:<textarea name="tell"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value=submit">
        }
```

Comment: Have you understood my question what I have to do here? how to pass the class I-V to  valid('<?php here?>).here i user select two or three subject how to pass these argument. I am not sure guide me please

Comment: what happen ? please help me

Comment: wasting my time and your time I ask a new question thanks for you suggestion.